# Why are my CSS properties being overridden/ignored?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having some issues with the CSS "hierarchy" (not sure if it's proper to call it a hierarchy). I'm trying to style the below bit of HTML.

```
<body>
  <section id="content">
    <article>
      <ul class="posts-list">
        <li class="post-item">
          <h2>[post title]</h2>
          <p class="item-description">...</p>
          <p class="item-meta">...</p>
        </li>
        ...
      </ul>
    </article>
  </section>
</body>
```

Since section#content changes on every page I have, I wanted to maintain consistent styles across all of them, so I wrote some "global" CSS rules.

```
#content {
  color: #000;
  margin-left: 300px;
  max-width: 620px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#content p,
#content li {
  color: #111;
  font: 16px / 24px serif;
}
```

I wanted to style HTML within a `ul.posts-list` differently, so I wrote these rules.

```
li.post-item > * {
  margin: 0px;
}

.item-description {
  color: #FFF;
}

.item-meta {
  color: #666;
}
```

However, I ran into some issues. Here is how Chrome is rendering the CSS:

[image: Screenshot of how Chrome is rendering my CSS]

For some reason, the rules `#content p, #content li` are overriding my rules for `.item-description` and `.item-meta`. My impression was that class/id names are considered specific and thus higher priority. However, it seems that I have a misunderstanding of how CSS works. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Also, where can I read up more about how this hierarchy works?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Elements id have the priority in CSS since they are the most specific.
You just have to use the id:

```
#content li.post-item > * {
  margin: 0px;
}

#content .item-description {
  color: #FFF;
}

#content .item-meta {
  color: #666;
}
```

Basically id have the priority on class which the priority on tags(p,li,ul, h1...). To override the rule, just make sure you have the priority ;)

Comment: +1'd for code, but a few links couldn't hurt! [official specification on specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) and [friendly cheat sheet](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

The "hierarchy" in which CSS rules are measured is called specificity. Each part of a CSS rule has an actual numerical base-10 value. IDs are worth 100 while classes are only 10.

For more information see http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 4):

Targeting ID's is more specific than targeting classes. More specific styling will overwrite less specific styling. It should be noted that in-line styling in HTML is more specific and will therefore overwrite ID-targeted styling. In other words:

```
<p style="color:white" id="itemDescId" class="item-description">...</p>
```

With the CSS:

```
p{color:blue;}
#itemDescId{color:red;}
.item-description{color:green}
```

The text will appear white - not because it's closest to the html code, but because it's higher in the specificity hierarchy. If you remove the inline styling (and you normally should for cleaner more manageable code), then the text would become red. Remove the ID and it will be green. And finally it will be blue once the class is removed.

This is one of the more complex topics to understand in CSS, and I'm only scratching the surface, but the easiest description I've found on how CSS specificity works is over at CSS tricks:

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2):

My response should have been a "comment" on the answer, but I have the correct fix although #tibo answered correctly:

```
li.post-item > * {
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.item-description {
  color: #FFF !important;
}

.item-meta {
  color: #666 !important;
}
```

The `!important` rule will override the order of evaluation between id and class.

Here is a link to an article, [When Using !important is The Right Choice](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/), that will help you to understand... it made my life easier :)

Answer (score -2):

Better to follow the CSS standards.
choose css selector and makeit under its parent then u may not to get conflicts when loading css fles (like .css files)

Comment: Could you elaborate or give a code sample of what you mean? I don't quite follow what you are saying.