# Add css when text is available

Tags: javascript, search, find

I have some pages, and some page have a this text : " Hello , im am ... "
So, I want to add css when the above text is available.
* My text has no element.

Thanks

Comment: Question is unclear. What is an example html?

Comment: Add text in html belongs to an element

Comment: Do you have any piece of code to show us? If not, you should!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer this question without any html to reference, but if you simply have text that's not inside a `<p>`, `<span>`, or another relevant tag, you could add css styles to the `<body>` element. For example, you could add this to your css file:

```
body {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is impossible without putting the text into SOME other tag, e.g. `<div>` `<span>` `<p>`.

One thing to note about CSS is that CSS rules work all the time. [They can be overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442670/why-are-my-css-properties-being-overridden-ignored), but they are applied everywhere, all the time. If there is nothing to apply a CSS rule too, then nothing is affected.

If you want to only affect one set of text, your HTML will need to look something like this:

```
<span id="myText"> Hello , im am ... </span>
```

Then your CSS will look something like:

```
#myText {
    color:#00FF00; // or whatever you need to do
}
```

If you have more than one set of text per page that you need to style in CSS, you have this option too:

```
<span class="myTextClass"> Hello , im am ... </span>
```

And then, of course the CSS:

```
.myTextClass {
    color:#00FF00; // or whatever you need to do
}
```