# stylesheet is not used correctly the html file, but it works fine for the other html file

Tags: html, css

Hello I have define general styles for my Website, but their wasn't apply for my stylesheet. I don't know why. Thank you for the helps.

my css:

```
* {
    font-size:11px
   }
input{
    background-color: #4CBAF7;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid darkolivegreen;
    height: 6%;
    width: 10%;
}
select{
    background-color: #4CBAF7;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid darkolivegreen;
    height: 6%;
    width: 10%;
    
}
button{
    background-color: #4CBAF7;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid darkolivegreen;
    height: 6%;
    width: 10%;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-color: darkolivegreen;
}
```

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OMP-System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="artikelSuche.js"></script>
    <style>
        .form-control::placeholder {
            color: white;
            opacity: 1;
            /* Firefox */
        }

        :-ms-input-placeholder {
            /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
            color: white;
        }

        ::-ms-input-placeholder {
            /* Microsoft Edge */
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body class="startseite">
    <h1 class="bootstrapH1">Artikelabfrage</h1>
    <hr id="horizontalLine">
    <div id="alleArtikel">
        <button id="deleteAllFilterBtn" onclick="deleteAllFilter()">Alle Filtereinstellungen löschen</button>
        <input id="artikelnummerInput" class="form-control" type="text" onkeyup="filterByAll()"
            placeholder="Artikelnummer" maxlength="6">
        <input id="materialbezeichnung1Input" class="form-control" type="text" onkeyup="filterByAll()"
            placeholder="Materialbezeichnung1">
        <input id="materialbezeichnung2Input" class="form-control" type="text" onkeyup="filterByAll()"
            placeholder="Materialbezeichnung2">
        <select id="teileartInput" onchange="getValueFromTeileart(this)">
            <option value="">Teileart</option>
            <option value="Kaufartikel">Kaufartikel</option>
            <option value="Fertigungsartikel">Fertigungsartikel</option>
            <option value="Endprodukt" selected="selected">Endprodukt</option>
        </select>
        <select id="materialklassenInput" onchange="getValueFromMaterialklasse(this)">
            <option value="">Materialklasse</option>
        </select>
        <select id="artikelstatusInput" onchange="getValueFromArtikelstatus(this)">
            <option value="">Artikelstatus</option>
        </select>
        <select id="gesperrtInput" onchange="getValueFromGesperrt(this)">
            <option value="">Gesperrt</option>
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Nein</option>
            <option value="1">Ja</option>
        </select>
        <div id="myCreatedTable">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <!--&#9650- fügte einen Pfeil ein, der die sortierweise angeben soll: desc und asc-->
                <tr class="bg-info">
                    <th data-column="artikelnummer" data-order="desc">Artikelnummer&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="gesperrt" data-order="desc">Gesperrt&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="materialbezeichnung1" data-order="desc">Materialbezeichnung1&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="materialbezeichnung2" data-order="desc">Materialbezeichnung2&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="materialbezeichnung3" data-order="desc">Materialbezeichnung3&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="teileart" data-order="desc">Teileart&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="materialklasse" data-order="desc">Materialklasse&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="gdp" data-order="desc">GDP&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="mengeneinheit" data-order="desc">Mengeneinheit&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="gewichtProMengeneinheitInMilligramm" data-order="desc">
                        Gewicht&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="chargenpflichtig" data-order="desc">Chargenpflichtig&#9650</th>
                    <th data-column="artikelstatus" data-order="desc">Artikelstatus&#9650</th>
                </tr>

                <tbody id="myTable">

                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="homeBtn" onclick="window.location.href = 'index.html'"><i class="fa fa-home" ></i> Home</button>

</body>

</html>
```

in my other html, where I am using the same stylesheet it is working but not with this one.
Here are the screenshot how it looks. All styles work, but input styles won't applied.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You should link your `stylesheet` after `bootstrap`

Comment: @Shuvo I have changed it but is also the same result and isn't working

Comment: Your style class might be overridden by the bootstrap class. Add ! important tag after the style.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442670/why-are-my-css-properties-being-overridden-ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your input element styles have overriden by .form-control class from Bootstrap.Add !important to your input element styles.

Comment: Thanks this solve one Problem, the other problem is, that i will make my buttons round. In my css I have write this: ```border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;```, but this also isn't work

Comment: Add !important to border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<body>`'s `class` before your css rules.
See [Cascade and inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance) for more details.

```css
.startseite * {
}

.startseite input {
}

.startseite select {
}

.startseite button {
}
```